# Using LINQ, select list of objects inside another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, select, linq-to-objects

```
public class ClassA
{
     public string MyString {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
     public List<ClassA> MyObjects {get; set;}
}

List<ClassB> classBList = new List<ClassB>();
var results = (from i in classBList select i.MyObjects).Distinct();
```

I want a distinct list of all the `ClassA` objects in the `classBList`.  How do I go about this using **LINQ**? I'm thinking about a nested query, but couldn't quite figure it out.  Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You're trying to select multiple result objects for each `ClassB` object in the original list.

Therefore, you're looking for the [`SelectMany` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
var results = classBList.SelectMany(b => b.MyObjects).Distinct();
```

If you want to use query expressions, you'll need to use [two `from` clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx#sectionToggle1):

```
var results = (from b in classBList from a in b.MyObjects select a).Distinct();
```

Comment: Does the query syntax you provide use SelectMany once translated? I'm a tad naive when it comes to query syntax since it always looks more verbose (except in join situations).

Comment: @Justin: Yes; those two expressions should compile identically.

Answer (score 18):

You want to use [`IEnumerable.SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) Extension Method to flatten the hierarchy:

```
var result = classBList.SelectMany(b => b.MyObjects).Distinct();
```